# IOS 8 - ABPeoplePickerNavigationController - Cancel delegate method works, others do not

Tags: objective-c, ios8, abpeoplepickerview

I've encountered a strange problem in my IOS 8 people picker delegate code.  Only the

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController    *)peoplePicker;
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

method is being called.  I have reviewed other questions and have made the important IOS 8 delegate method changes for selecting a contact by calling the old IOS 7 method

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:   (ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    [self peoplePickerNavigationController:peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:person property:property identifier:identifier];
}
```

but it is never called.

I am setting the delegate in the  calling viewcontroller didLoad,

and it works perfectly in ios 7.  This is a storyboard application.

I saw the same question asked in a comment here: [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController changes with iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806774/abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-changes-with-ios8)

but never found an answer.  Obviously a mistake somewhere on my part, but I can't find it.

UPDATE:  As requested, here is how I set the delegate:

```
self.picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
self.picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
```

And, in @interface:

```
@interface TreatmentsAddEntryTVC :    UITableViewController<UITextViewDelegate,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this delegate method instead and see if it hits:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person;
{
   // yes the below line is deprecated as of iOS 8
   [self peoplePickerNavigationController:peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:person];
}
```

Comment: Did you add "`<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>`" to your "`@interface`" declaration in your view controller's .h file?  Also, you should edit your question to show how you set the delegate in your view controller.

Comment: change your declaration to: "`@interface TreatmentsAddEntryTVC : UITableViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>`" and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - Doesn't work, idk whats wrongs when one delegate is being called and others are not !

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, especially when the answer makes no sense, but moving:

```
self.picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
self.picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
```

from didLoad to the method where I actually want to display the picker fixed the problem.  I have seen at least one other question on SO where this behavior was noted and discussed:

[Cannot select contact on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024611/cannot-select-contact-on-ios-8)

Comment: I am facing the same issue and i tried what you mentioned here, did you find any other solution ? Please share if you did.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering - that's all I can tell you.  If you are still stuck I will be happy to dig through my older code for anything that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For a project with iOS 8.1,
I replaced this method

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{ 
}
```

with this

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
}
```

And new method did hit when I selected a contact.